# Linq Sum without Group By

Tags: mysql, linq, asp.net-core

I want to understand how to do something basic like a simple query that sums an amount column and returns it as a type.

This is the query I'm trying to convert.

```
SELECT
  SUM( trans_trades.amount )
FROM
  trans_trades
INNER JOIN trans_series ON trans_series.id = trans_trades.series_id 
WHERE
  trans_trades.series_id IN (17, 18)
```

My view model:

```
public class TotalTransRaise
{
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```

Method:

```
public TotalTransRaise GetTotalTransRaise()
{
    _context = new MySQLDatabaseContext();

    var result = (from t1 in _context.TradesSeries
                join t2 in _context.TradesTrades on t1.Id equals t2.SeriesId
                where myInClause.Contains(t2.SeriesId)
                select new TotalTransRaise
                {
                    Total = (decimal) t2.Amount //this gives an error because Amount represents all the amounts because I can't apply .Sum() here to make it one summed aggregate, so the method thinks I should be casting TotalTransRaise as a list.   
                });

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Seems like there's an issue translating to sql. Can you try changing `Total` to `Decimal` type and removing the cast to `(int)` from your query?

Comment: I did that and it resolved that error, but now it's pointing at the t2.Amount.Sum(). I guess Sum doesn't exist in the "new" context?

Comment: We need two more things: which data library is this? (I guess Entity Framework core). And could you show the class model (esp. navigation properties).

Comment: Thanks, Gert. I finally sorted it out. I'm going to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the method to:

```
        public TotalTransRaise GetTotalTransRaise()
        {
            _context = new MySQLDatabaseContext();

            var result = _context.TradesSeries
                .Join(_context.TradesTrades, t1 => t1.Id, t2 => t2.SeriesId, (t1, t2) => new {t1, t2})
                .Where(t => myInClause.Contains(t.t2.SeriesId))
                .GroupBy(s => s.t1.Active)
                .Select(g => 
                    new TotalTransRaise
                    {
                        Total = g.Sum(x => x.t2.Amount)
                    }
                ).FirstOrDefault();
            return result;
        }
```